# I can't open .docx without it being in onedrive

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, onedrive, docx

Whenever I download a .docx file (word file), whether from my email or from the internet, word always brings up this error message:

[image: IMG:]

I do not know what is happening. Luckily, I have onedrive and therefore, if I move it into there, I can open it. But, I don't want to do that every time. What is happening and how can I fix that?

Comment: What version of Office do you have installed?  I suspect you have an online only version of Word installed, hence the reason, your able to open documents within OneDrive.

Comment: I am using Office 365. I use word offline

Comment: If you open Word, and then save a document to the desktop, then close the document.  Are you able to within Word open that document.  Instead of submitting commentary you should clarify your question

Comment: Please refer to [How to resolve the problem "Word experienced an error trying to open the file" ···](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2749199/how-to-resolve-the-problem-word-experienced-an-error-trying-to-open-th)

Comment: Thank you so much for that. I have had that problem for around 3 years, and this solution is perfect